# kernel space to snmp agent

Tags: linux-device-driver, snmp, net-snmp

I have message in kernel space and want to give this message to snmp agent (a user space program communicate via Ethernet)(net-snmp).
How can I give a message from kernel space to snmp agent?

a)find a receive call in snmp agent (socket receive function) and receive the message via Ethernet driver by using socket communication. it is possible or right way to do ?

b)send message to user space via raw socket communication applied in the driver. is it possible? because when using some function like socket in kernel it angry with me, is there alternative way and sensible.

c)send message to user space and in user space use socket communication send the message via loop-back to snmp agent?

d)none of them, is there brilliant way :?

Which one is right how can overcome this issue? Thanks for your consideration and time.

Comment: Depends on the message, but I would try to go the way that you insert an SKB in the kernel and agent will receive it naturally as network packet.

Comment: Message is a natural snmp question, but the connection is PCI and I used PCI media Ethernet driver, sorry for complicated information and thank you for your request.